# How to resize logical volume in Red Hat Linux

Tags: rhel, partition, lvm, resize2fs, lvreduce

Please guide that how to do following tasks with executing command.

- 1.Create a new physical volume, create a new volume group in the name of 
  `dataconresize`, vg extent is 16.00MB.
- 2.Create a new logical volume in the name of `datacopyresize` with the size of 50 extents and file system must `ext4`
- 3.Then mount it under `/dataresize`
- 4.Resize the logical volume, `logical-data` and it filesystem to 400MB.
- 5.Resize the logical volume, `logical-data` and it filesystem to 600MB. Make sure that the filesystem contents remain intact.

Note: partitions are seldom exactly the size requested,so any thing within the range of 370MB to 430MB is acceptable.

**I tried first three steps as follows.**

```
fdisk /dev/vdb
```

----- > Create the Partition and set it's type 8e (which is LVM type)

```
partprobe /dev/vdb
```

-----> get the partition

```
pvcreate /dev/vdb1
vgcreate -s 16M dataconresize /dev/vdb1
vgdisplay
```

-----> Check the vg extent size, its should be this (PE Size 16.00 MiB)

```
lvcreate -l 50 -n datacopyresize dataconresize
lvdisplay
```

-----> Check the size of extents

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/dataconresize/datacopyresize
```

-----> Make a filesystem on it

```
mkdir -p /dataresize
```

-----> Create Directory to mount on it

```
blkid /dev/dataconresize/datacopyresize
```

-----> Get the UUID of `/dev/datacontainer/datacopy`

```
vim /etc/fstab
```

-----> Create the mount point inside the fstab

```
UUID=C553-2BF5 /dataresize ext4 defaults 0 0  
mount -a

df -hT
```

-----> get the mount point of it

But I am stuck with task 4 and task 5.

Answer (score 1):

You have a LV called "datacopyresize" of size *PE_size* x 50 = 800 Mb.

To shrink it to 400 Mb you will need to resize first the filesystem, then the LV (otherwise you'll lose data):

```
resize2fs /dev/dataconresize/datacopyresize 400M
lvresize -L 400M /dev/dataconresize/datacopyresize
```

Then to extend it to 600 Mb, you first resize the LV and then the filesystem:

```
lvresize -L 600M /dev/dataconresize/datacopyresize
resize2fs /dev/dataconresize/datacopyresize 600M
```

Note: you could use instead `lvreduce` to shrink the LV and `lvextend` to extend it; the advantage of `lvresize` is that it offers an unique command for both operations.
Also, you could pass the `--resizefs` argument to `lvresize` to automatically resize the fs along with the LV, instead of using `resize2fs`; I suggest you try my method, which uses two separate commands, to better understand what you're doing.